# How to combine jquery UI/Tabs with ImageFlow based on JavaScript

Tags: jquery, imageflow

Hi I'm currently trying to embed the ImageFlow Plugin into a single Tab, which is created by the jQuery Plugin UI/Tabs. My Problem is that the ImageFlow-generated Interface is not shown correctly. I think this might be, because the div is invisible/hidden on initialisation. Is there a way to show the imageFlow inside a Tab?

I tried the code snipped from The UI-Tabs-Page, which does not work for me:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance
Daniel

http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Introduction

```
Sorry I'm not allowed to post the Link to jQuery UI Tabs
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out my solution:
Its necesary to specify a width for the div ImageFlow container inside the Tab

```
<div id="tab"><div id="xyz">...</div></div>

#xyz {
 width300px;
}
```

Like this will work.